# Here Map SDK IOS (Premium) tap on the marker

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

Good afternoon, who once worked with heremap sdk premium for ios. How do I make it possible to click on the NMAMapMarker? What they have written in the documentation does not describe it, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

there are different option available for NMAMapMarker to use.
This represents a marker used to display an icon on a geographical position on a map. The map handles proper placement of icons on the screen as well as panning and rotation.

+mapMarkerWithGeoCoordinates:
+mapMarkerWithGeoCoordinates:icon:
+mapMarkerWithGeoCoordinates:image:
coordinates
icon
draggable
draggingOffsetEnabled
anchorOffset
-initWithGeoCoordinates:
-initWithGeoCoordinates:icon:
-initWithGeoCoordinates:image:
-setAnchorOffsetUsingLayoutPosition:
-setSize:forZoomLevel:
-setSize:forZoomRange:
-resetIconSize

Check for more details : https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.18/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(im)initWithGeoCoordinates.

Please revert with your code implementation in case of any further concern.